# Risc-v linker stack and heap sections are empty. ARM are not. Why?

Tags: linker, arm, riscv, linker-scripts

I have a long linker script but at the end of it, I do the following:

```
    .heap (COPY): {
        __heap_start = .;
        KEEP(*(.heap*))
        __heap_end = .;
    } > RAM

    .stack (COPY): {
        KEEP(*(.stack*))
    } > RAM

    __stack_start = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
    __stack_end = __stack_start - SIZEOF(.stack);
    PROVIDE(_stack = __stack_start);

    ASSERT(__stack_end >= __heap_end, "Stack overflow in region RAM")
```

This way I can figure out the bare minimum RAM I need for the code to fit. It works fine in ARM and when I look at the linker map, I see .stack and .heap not empty. However, when I do the same for RISC-V, the regions are empty. Is there a reason?

The code I am using for both are similar. I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc and riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc.

Comment: compiler and linker script have nothing to do with each other.  the linker script is at the whim of the author, most are grossly over complicated most of that stuff is not necessary or can be cone easily in some other way.  Likewise no reason to assume any two linker scripts for a single target are relatable much less any two linker scripts for different targets.

Comment: the linker scripts (can) have an intimate relationship with the bootstrap and sometimes with the C library but the C library is independent or can be from the toolchain (compiler, assembler, linker).  Not uncommon to see the bootstrap and linker script to be part of the C library.  would make no sense to have one related to a toolchain without a C library to go with it.

Comment: @old_timer I design custom chips from Verilog code so linker script is necessary for me. Otherwise, the software doesn't understand which memory to use for the code. I am a bit new to this topic and resources are very limited, so excuse me if my questions are dumb.
If my understanding is correct, these sections are generated by the compiler. The linker's job is to combine the sections into one object file.

Comment: when I dump the final object file, I see non-empty heap and stack sections with ARM compiler and empty heap and stack sections with RISC-V compiler. The question then is why does the ARM compiler generate them while the RISC-V compiler doesn't generate them. Do I need to pass an extra argument with the RISC-V compiler to get them to show or is this feature not implemented?